# How can I create a bar chart which has a table below that displays the individual bar values like an excel chart table

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to create a chart table like one's in excel using dash but I am not exactly sure how to implement this. I tried displaying a data-table below the graph but the table does not align with the data points in graph. Kindly let me know if there is a way to create such a chart table in dash.

This is how I want my plot to look like:

[image]

This is how  my current plot looks like

[image]

The following is the code that I am using:

```
dbc.Col(
[
    html.H3("Graph 5"),
    dcc.Graph(
        figure={'data': [go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 1, 2], marker=dict(color='skyblue')),
                         go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[0.3, 0.4, 0.1], opacity=1,
                                marker=dict(color='skyblue', line=dict(color='black', width=5)))],                                                  
                                'layout': go.Layout(barmode='overlay')}
    ),
    dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table_3',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df1.columns],
            data=df.to_dict('records')
            ),
    html.Div(html.H4(""), style={'padding-bottom':'50px'})
],
md=6,
```

)

Comment: Hi Prashank. Welcome to SO. Please upload some example of the code you have tried, and perhaps an image of your result. Also, when asking questions, it is helpful to refer to the suggestions on creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the suggestions. I have updated my post. Can you please take a look and help me out with this. Thanks in advance.